# insert icons into a telegram message using python

Tags: python

I am trying to reproduce the follow output (see the pic, please):

[image]

I already made the right code to create the text message and send it to telegram channels, but I don't know how to insert the flag, clock and ball icon into the message.

This is my working code:

```
    match = "Leeds United V Watford"
    tournamentsts = "England :- Championship"
    resultlive3 = "55'"
    resultlive1 = "0-0"

    import telebot
    from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
    from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser, InputPeerChannel
    from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events


    # get your api_id, api_hash, token
    # from telegram as described above
    api_id = xxxxxxxx
    api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    
    my_channel_id = -1000000000000 #destination

    message = "LTDSH 0-0 Alerts\n\n" + match + "\n" + tournamentsts + "\nElapsed Time: " + resultlive3 + "\nScore: " + resultlive1



    # your phone number
    phone = '+001234567'

    # creating a telegram session and assigning
    # it to a variable client
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

    # connecting and building the session
    client.connect()

    # in case of script ran first time it will
    # ask either to input token or otp sent to
    # number or sent or your telegram id
    if not client.is_user_authorized():

        client.send_code_request(phone)
        
        # signing in the client
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))


    try:
        # receiver user_id and access_hash, use
        # my user_id and access_hash for reference
        #receiver = InputPeerUser('user_id', 'user_hash')

        # sending message using telegram client
        client.send_message(my_channel_id, message, parse_mode='html')
    except Exception as e:
        #client.send_message(token, message, parse_mode='html')
    #except Exception as e:
        # there may be many error coming in while like peer
        # error, wrong access_hash, flood_error, etc
        print(e);

    # disconnecting the telegram session
    client.disconnect()
```

I need to insert the flag before the variable value tournaments, the clock before resultlive3 and the ball before resultlive1.
I hope my question is clear, I am a newbie of python

Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found the right solution